# Software caused connection abort during mvn deploy

Tags: cloudbees

I am getting this error when trying to deploy on my cloudbees repository.

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) @ my-portal ---
Downloading: dav:https://repository-myproject.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/myproject/my-portal/0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
9 janv. 2013 23:05:13 org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
Uploading: https://repository-myproject.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/myproject/my-portal/0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/myproject-portal-0.0.3-20130109.220513-1.war
9 janv. 2013 23:05:14 org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
9 janv. 2013 23:06:54 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

The file is a war which is about 20MB. The same error occurs if I deploy from my laptop at work, from my computer at home thru maven deploy command, or even using cyberduck. It happens sometimes after 1,5MB has been uploaded or after 5MB, it's not always the same.

Is there a limitation on file size? 
I set european URL but don't know if it's important.
Any hints?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error is not caused by file size limitation, but an error on forge. Please contact support@cloudbees.com if this occurs again.

Not sure what you mean by "european URL"